# Shape keys and geometry nodes

Tags: shape-keys, geometry-nodes

Is it possible to add a parameter or attribute in the geometry node tab to affect shape keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Monday there is this blender live stream on YouTube and I asked in the chat if it is possible to use shape keys as attributes. I got the answer (short version): not yet.
So I guess it will come with the next updates(comment written during 2.92)

Greetings Tobi

Comment: 3.0 is out now. Have you seen any news on this?

Comment: There is now a way to replicate the functionality of Shape Keys using Geometry Nodes. [Here's how.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/259206/2952) :-)