# About getting vertex positions between two models by geometry node

Tags: modeling, scripting, geometry-nodes

I want to do the following.

I want to acquire the vertex position information of two models A and B with the same structure at the geometry node, blend them, and then reflect the result in the model.

In addition to that, if possible, I want to control the mixing ratio of the vertex positions of A and B with the vertex weight value.

Is it feasible?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean with "blend them"?

Comment: I'm a beginner so I'm not sure if the blend is the correct expression. To be precise, it may be more correct to reflect the difference in the vertex positions of the model.

In the following figure, the vertices are located at 50% of the vertices of the B model with respect to the A model.

Comment: That is, 0% is the position of the apex of A, 50% is the position of the red line, and 100% is the position of the apex of B (probably acting like a shape key).

Comment: For a single frame, you can change it using the shape keys. But my ultimate goal is to automatically mix the animations for all frames at any ratio of two Allenbic file animations with the same mesh structure model but different animations.

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be reproduced with a geometry node. Either method is fine. Do you have any hints on how to reproduce it?

Comment: hi,chris  thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I would like to give up this time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To achieve this goal, you would only need to get the positions of the two objects with `Transfer Attribute` and calculate a direction vector from it.

If you then scale this vector with a value between $0$ and $1$, you can create the position between the two objects and apply it to the geometry with `Set Position`.

[image]

*Note: the two objects would have to have the same number of points in this case, of course, because here the positions are queried via the index of the points.*

Comment: Hell0,quellenform  That's the perfect answer I wanted.
Thank you from the bottom of my heart！

Comment: quellenform, I'm trying to expand on this awesome answer of yours by adding all the features of regular Shape Keys. But I got stuck with curve objects... the handles aren't deforming correctly. I just [asked a question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269008/) about it, in case you're curious to check it out. :-)

Comment: @Mentalist ...I have looked at your question and written an answer. I hope I have succeeded to some extent: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273155/145249